# linq, Ajax error where query returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

i get this error, i am trying to searching thru a list using linq.

when i find result it works fine..but when i don't have a result i get this error, which does not make sense to me.

Anyone can point me in the right direction on how to debug this error?

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.ArgumentException: Cannot deserialize. The data does not correspond to valid JSON.
Parameter name: data

Sample code:

```
IEnumerable<ClassA> listClassA = bar.ToList(); // at this point list contains values.

decimal b = listClassA.FirstOrDefault(a => a.date.Month == 9).number; // at this point if there are no results it crashes and i get the error.
```

Comment: -1. This is not a question.

Comment: What does that error mean? i am trying to debug it.

Comment: That means that if you expect anybody in the world to be able to help you should at least post some code...

Comment: please post your code that cause the error

Comment: If `bar.ToList()` actually succeeded, you need to show the code for `ClassA` because the `date` property (or `date.Month` or `.number`) does _something_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code & comments provided, `ClassA.date`, `ClassA.date.Month`, or `ClassA.number` do some parsing and to get a "good" answer, you'll have to post the code for those properties.

There's a slight chance, a typo of `data` instead of `date` is causing the exception but it's really hard to tell.

For what it's worth (because this isn't the cause of the error you've provided) you have to check for null.

```
decimal b = listClassA.FirstOrDefault(a => a.date.Month == 9).number;
```

... should be:

```
decimal b;
var septemberData = listClassA.FirstOrDefault(a => a.date.Month == 9);

if (septemberData != null)
{
    b = septemberData.number;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When there are no results, presumably your call to `FirstOrDefault()` will return null.  But you are then trying to access the property `number` of this null reference.  You should check for null before doing this:

```
var firstItem = listClassA.FirstOrDefault(a => a.date.Month == 9);
decimal b = (firstItem != null ? firstItem.number : -1); // or pick some other sensible default value
```